MergeShapes fails when declared as Object instead of explicitly as ShapeRange
I have a section of code that uses Late Binding on PowerPoint, and one of the actions that I wish to perform is to Merge 2 shapes.
When I attempt this, I get "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".  Specifically, this only occurs when I initially declare the ShapeRange as an Object (because, Late Binding), rather than as a ShapeRange (which requires Early Binding).  When calling the following 2 functions within PowerPoint, the first (MergeShapes_Success) will succeed, while the second (MergeShapes_Failure) will fail. (The first function will also succeed if called from another Application using Early Binding)
The only difference between the two functions is whether shpRng is Declared as Object or ShapeRange.
Private Function MergeShapes_Success(ByRef Shape1 As Object, Shape2 As Object) As Boolean
    Dim shpRng As PowerPoint.ShapeRange 'This is the only line that differs
    
    If Not (Shape1.Parent Is Shape2.Parent) Then
        MsgBox "Shapes to Merge must be on the same Slide!", vbCritical, "Error!"
        MergeShapes_Success = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set shpRng = Shape1.Parent.Shapes.Range(Array(Shape1.ZOrderPosition, Shape2.ZOrderPosition))
    
    shpRng.MergeShapes msoMergeUnion
    ' Shapes Merge Successfully
    
    MergeShapes_Success = True
End Function

Private Function MergeShapes_Failure(ByRef Shape1 As Object, Shape2 As Object) AS Boolean
    Dim shpRng As Object 'This is the only line that differs
    
    If Not (Shape1.Parent Is Shape2.Parent) Then
        MsgBox "Shapes to Merge must be on the same Slide!", vbCritical, "Error!"
        MergeShapes_Failure = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set shpRng = Shape1.Parent.Shapes.Range(Array(Shape1.ZOrderPosition, Shape2.ZOrderPosition))
    
    shpRng.MergeShapes msoMergeUnion
    ' /*************************
    ' ** Run-time error '13': **
    ' ** Type mismatch        **
    ' *************************/
    
    MergeShapes_Failure = True
End Function

I have checked the TypeName of shpRng after I Set it (which returns "ShapeRange" in both cases), and I have confirmed that TypeOf shpRng Is ShapeRange in both cases too.
Is anyone able to advise as to why this happens and, ideally, how to make this function… well, function, with Late Binding?

Maybe you don't need the intermediate shaperange variable at all ?
Shape1.Parent.Shapes.Range(Array(Shape1.ZOrderPosition, Shape2.ZOrderPosition)).MergeShapes msoMergeUnion

@TimWilliams A good suggestion, but (unfortunately) that also throws the Type Mismatch error — which is how I ended up using Dim shpRng As ShapeRange for the Early Binding version in the first place

The error message does not mean that the declaration (As Object) is wrong... The parameters of `MergeShapes1 are not suitable. Please, test the adapted function:
Private Function MergeShapes_Failure(ByRef Shape1 As Object, Shape2 As Object) As Boolean
    Dim shpRng As Object 
    
    If Not (Shape1.Parent Is Shape2.Parent) Then
        MsgBox "Shapes to Merge must be on the same Slide!", vbCritical, "Error!"
        MergeShapes_Failure = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set shpRng = Shape1.Parent.Shapes.Range(Array(Shape1.ZOrderPosition, Shape2.ZOrderPosition))

    
    On Error GoTo Problem
     shpRng.MergeShapes 1, Shape1 'The second parameter is required, even if in documentation is Optional
                                  'Using Late Binding the constant msoMergeUnion does not have much of a meaning, too...
    
     MergeShapes_Failure = True
     Exit Function
Problem:
    
End Function


This has worked!  It is certainly rather unusual — I wonder why the second parameter stops being Optional when you don't explicitly declare shpRng As ShapeRange, or skip the Set shpRng =  step?
(Also, the MsoMergeCmd Enumerator is available in other Office Applications, even if the MergeShapes method is not — i.e. if you are Late Binding into Excel or Access, then msoMergeUnion does exist and have meaning.)

@Chronocidal It looks to be a bug. PP is only guessing when it knows what you try doing. In case of Late Binding it is not able to do it, I am afraid. Then, I am afraid that you are wrong related to msoMergeUnion unicity in all Office applications... You probably have a reference to PowerPoint. At least, in some Excel versions (2007 certainly) it does not have any meaning. If you try Debug.Print msoMergeUnion having Option Explicit on top of the module, it will raise a compile error: Variable not defined... Without Option Explicit it will take it as 0, since it should be 1...

No reference to Powerpoint (i.e. it still shows up in Excel even with a brand-new freshly created Workbook), but I am using Office 365: MsoMergeCmd (and, through it, msoMergeUnion) is part of the core "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" reference.  I can't say when it was added to that though.

@Chronocidal It can be as you say in that specific version. I tried supplying a solution able to work in all environments containing VBA (automation from CorelLDRAW for Excel and PowerPoint, for instance). But I can swear that using that constant it will  not work on Excel 2007... I have just tested the constant value in Excel 2007 and it raise an error.

I though that in PowerPoint 2007, Shape Merging was still only available via CommandBars.ExecuteMso, and not yet exposed as a VBA Method?  (Which would make the lack of MsoMergeCmd rather a moot point…)
